# setting up with Ruby (cannot load such file json/pure)

Tags: ruby

Hi I was working on an API https://developers.supportbee.com/platform/overview

while doing
`bin/sbapp new APP_SLUG` 
I got the error

```
/home/nitesh/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in `block in materialize': Could not find multi_json-1.3.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

after which I again tried  `gem install multi_json`
and then again got the error

```
Successfully installed multi_json-1.5.0
/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- json/pure (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I got this error while  installing rails. I solved it by running `gem install json_pure` 
and then running `gem install rails` again.

Comment: That worked for me (while trying to install compass, and getting a similar error to the above).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do a

```
bundle install
```

first and then run as

```
bundle exec bin/sbapp new APP_SLUG
```

Comment: Thanks . I had already tried this but for bundle install I need to have rake so I tried gem install rake , but that gives me the same : cannot load such file -- json/pure (LoadError)

Comment: had the same problem and this is definitly not the solution... `gem install json_pure` is the right way to get this fixed!

Comment: This doesn't even work on a centOS system, the comment is better than the answer, use `gem install json_pure` to solve this.

Comment: `gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc json_pure` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using join 1.7.7 and have same error, so i fix by update json to version 1.8.1:

```
vim Gemfile
```

edit json version to '1.8.1'

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

and this work!